# Write to MySQL from VB.Net. VB uses comma, but the database only accept period

Tags: mysql, vb.net

First I am showing some data in a datagridview and then it’s possible to double click it and have the value entered in a textbox called: txtDecimal

```
txtDecimal.text = CStr(dtgAnsatte.CurrentRow.Cells("Price").Value)
```

Then I want the user to change this value and write it back to the database. The problem is in MySQL, it only accept values like 200.00, 240.58 with periods. But when I am writing it to VB the format is 200,00 and 240,58. Is there any way to get around this? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to write to the database?

Comment: "INSERT INTO ‘database’ (‘Price’) VALUES (‘” & txtDecimal.text & “’);

Comment: I think you need to look into using prepared statements. For one, they're more secure and for another they don't create problems when writing dates and numbers. There's a decent tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlvb/). It has an insert sample about a third of the way down the page. I'm sure there are plenty of others. You may experience some pain moving to the prepared statements but trust me you'll code faster going forward.

Comment: In addition to Ed Gibbs statement, my guess is that users are entering commas or the text is being formatted like that.  Try to remove the commas (and dollar sign if it is there as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it is formatting it with a comma because of your localization settings.  Try this

```
txtDecimal.text = CDbl(dtgAnsatte.CurrentRow.Cells("Price").Value).ToString(New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", False))
```

This should output it with a "." rather than a ","